# How to find surface area of a 2D image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to find the surface area of an image in matlab. Please find the image below:
[image]
I have implemented a code but it is giving me an error.

```
BW = imread('Intensity3.jpg');
figure, imshow(BW);
area = bwarea(BW);
```

Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 749-by-5253 and the size of the right side is 749-by-1049-by-3.

Error in bwarea (line 39)
bb(2:end-1,2:end-1) = b;

Error in I2 (line 3)
area = bwarea(BW);

Comment: `bwarea` takes a binary image. Apparently yours is RGB. You'll need to threshold your image in some way that makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the response.